# awk to capture element upto space or using special escape character

Tags: awk

Trying to extract the 5th element in `$1` after the `-` upto the space or `\\`. If a `/` was used then the script `awk -F'[-/'] 'NR==0{print; next} {print $0"\t""\t"$5}' file` works as expected. Thank you :).

**file**  --tab-delimited--

```
00-0000-L-F-Male    \\path\to   xxx xxx
00-0001-L-F-Female  \\path\to   xxx xxx
```

desired (last field has two tabs before)

```
00-0000-L-F-Male    \\path\to   xxx xxx         Male
00-0001-L-F-Female  \\path\to   xxx xxx         Female
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'-[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' 'NR==0{print; next} {print $0"\t""\t"$5}' file

00-0000-L-F-Male        \\path\to       xxx     xxx
00-0001-L-F-Female      \\path\to       xxx     xxx
```

**awk 2**

```
awk -F'[-\\]' 'NR==0{print; next} {print $0"\t""\t"$5}' file

awk: fatal: Unmatched [ or [^: /[-\]/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk -F'[-\t]' -v OFS='\t\t' '{print $0, $5}' file
00-0000-L-F-Male    \\path\to   xxx xxx     Male
00-0001-L-F-Female  \\path\to   xxx xxx     Female
```

Regarding your scripts:

> awk
>
> `awk -F'-[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' 'NR==0{print; next} {print $0"\t""\t"$5}' file`

1. `-F'-[[:space:]][[:space:]]+'` says that your fields are separated by a `-` followed by 2 or more spaces, which they aren't.
2. `NR==0{foo}` says "do `foo` for line number 0" but there is no line number 0 in any input.

> awk 2
>
> `awk -F'[-\\]' 'NR==0{print; next} {print $0"\t""\t"$5}' file`

1. `-F'[-\\]'` appears to be trying to set FS to a minus sign or a backslash, but you already told us your fields are tab-separated, not backslash-separated.
2. When setting `FS` this way it goes through a few different phases of interpretation, converting a shell string to an awk string, converting an awk string to a regexp, and using the regexp as a field separator, so you need several layers of escaping, not just 1, to make a backslash literal. If unsure, keep adding backslashes until the warnings and errors go away.

Comment: Alright, multi-char `FS` is quite nice.

Answer (score 3):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk -F'\t' '{n=split($1, a, /-/); print $0 FS FS a[(n > 4 ? 5 : n)]}' file

00-0000-L-F-Male        \\path\to       xxx xxx         Male
00-0001-L-F-Female      \\path\to       xxx xxx         Female
```

`a[(n > 4 ? 5 : n)]` expression gets 5th element from array if there are 5 or more elements in array otherwise it gets last element.

Comment: That's a good use of the ternary to protect the split array bounds.

Answer (score 3):

Presuming your file is `'\t'` separated with one-tab per field and you want an empty field before the `Male/Female` output, you can use:

```bash
awk -F"\t" '{ split($1,arr,"-"); print $0 "\t\t" arr[5] }' filetabs.txt
```

**Example Use/Output**

Where `filetabs.txt` contains your sample data with tab field-separators you would get:

```
$ awk -F"\t" '{ split($1,arr,"-"); print $0 "\t\t" arr[5] }' filetabs.txt
00-0000-L-F-Male        \\path\to       xxx xxx         Male
00-0001-L-F-Female      \\path\to       xxx xxx         Female
```

Answer (score 3):

With `perl` one liner which supports lazy match we can try following code. Written and tested in shown samples only.

```
perl -pe 's/^((?:.*?-)+)([^[:space:]]+)([[:space:]]+.*)$/\1\2\3\t\t\2/'  Input_file
```

***OR*** above could be written as following also:

```
perl -pe 's/^((?:.*?-)+)(\S+)(\s+.*)$/\1\2\3\t\t\2/' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for used regex above. Here is the [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tJV4Ty/1) for used regex in code.

```
^(                ##From starting of the value creating one capturing group here.
   (?:            ##Opening non-capturing group here.
   .*?-           ##Using lazy match till - here.
   )+             ##Closing non-capturing group here with matching 1 OR more occurrences of this.
 )                ##Closing 1st capturing group here.
([^[:space:]]+)   ##Creating 2nd capturing group and matching all non-spaces in it.
([[:space:]]+.*)$ ##Creating 3rd capturing group which matches spaces till end of the value.
```

Comment: perl to the rescue. While I love the capability perl provides, startup-time was always a bit on the slow side. Hard to beat the REGEX capability thought.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, No one can beat `awk` IMHO(no edge cases involved here) :)

Comment: I'll tell you what, those coders that wrote `awk` knew what they were doing. Blistering fast and incredibly capable. And, if you write in C, you find `awk` is basically a flexible scriptable version with simplified REGEX handling. I couldn't agree more with your `awk` assessment.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, yeah totally agree with you here. We are `awk` LOVERS :) for a reason for sure. Is there any doubt about it? naahh :)